# How to create adjacent Material Buttons with single border in-between

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I want to have two [Material Buttons](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) directly next to each other with a 1dp-wide separator line between them, [like this (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7miY.jpg).
[image]

I've tried setting custom background drawables on the buttons, but Material Buttons [no longer allow this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton).

My next attempt was to use Material Buttons' `stroke` attributes, but I can't find a way to apply the stroke to a single side.

I've also tried inserting a 1dp-wide View between the buttons, which could be a solution, but I haven't been able to programatically set the height and position of that View without becoming too complicated.

The two buttons are currently in a ConstraintLayout, but I've also tried nesting them inside a RelativeLayout inside the ConstraintLayout.

Here's the attempt inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/registration_cl">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/signin_social_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/signin_btn_back">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_btn_facebook"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#525352"
            android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proximanova"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white_ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_facebook_icon_fb_socialshare_"
            app:iconTint="@color/white_ffffff"
            tools:alpha="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/signin_social_div"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white_ffffff"
            android:background="@color/white_ffffff"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/signin_btn_facebook"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_btn_google"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/signin_social_div"
            android:backgroundTint="#525352"
            android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proximanova"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Google"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white_ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:iconSize="8dp"
            tools:alpha="1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expected there to be a simpler solution to adding a one-side-border besides programatically sizing and positioning a view between the buttons.

Comment: Add a view between the two buttons, with `layout_height`: `match_parent` and `layout_width`: `1dp` or `0.5dp`, whatever fits your requirement. If you can share the whole XML, I can help further.

Comment: @kushpf thank you. I updated the code to include the full xml tree and attempted your suggestion. If I set `layout_height` to `match_parent` the view becomes the height of the entire screen, so I've temporarily set it to 50dp. This is what led me to the solution of programatically calculating the height and position but that just seems too complicated, I'd rather alter the design than deal with that.

Comment: Where is `@id/signin_btn_back` defined? Cannot see in the layout that you've shared. The height of relativelayout might be affected due to the constraint with signin_btn_back as well.

Comment: @kushpf it is a sibling of the RelativeLayout, and is constrained to the bottom of its parent. So it ends up at the bottom of the screen with the RelativeLayout directly above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views are not constrained inside the RelativeLayout, that's why the `View` is taking full height. Instead, using `LinearLayout` to achieve the result would be much easier. Following code should help:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/signin_social_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/signin_btn_back">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_btn_facebook"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/signin_social_div"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ... />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_btn_google"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayour` makes the rendering faster as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was under the impression RelativeLayout was more efficient but I've looked into it more and I believe you are correct. This solution works perfectly, except I also needed to add `android:insetBottom="0dp"` and `android:insetTop="0dp"` to both MaterialButtons to get the LinearLayout to properly fit to the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly what you are looking for but it is very simple.
You can do something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:strokeWidth="0dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON 1"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:strokeWidth="0dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON 2"
    />
```

You can remove the border using `strokeWidth=0dp` and you can apply different corner radius using the [**`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute (it requires the version 1.1.0).

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Left" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">16dp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Button.Right" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

The final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented your solution but with no difference in result. Setting the divider view's `layout_height` to `match_parent` caused the view to become the full height of the display and the buttons got pushed off-screen somewhere. Setting the height to `50dp` gives me [this](https://imgur.com/F3ylyoh). Could you post the surrounding nested RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout in your example?

Comment: In my example I'am using a transparent background (not white).Of course it depends by your full layout. If you don't want to calculate the height you can also use something like `android:layout_marginRight="1dp"` in your button.

Comment: Ah, I see why you did that now. Good solution but the background on this screen is actually a video rather than a solid color so I need the gap between the buttons to specifically be white.